# Doing entire graph traversal and updating nodes with new relationships i.e, via neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Like this following link says http://www.neo4j.org/graphgist?8173017 for building similarity relationships between nodes i wrote a query to update nodes with common primary interest. In my case i had 60k nodes,200k interestedIn relationships between entity and relationship.

```
Match path=(p:Entity)-[:interestedIn]->(i:Interest)<-[:interestedIn]-(p1:Entity) return count(path)
```

Gives me 44404280 . 
The plan is to create a new relationship of similarity with value(common/total) as attribute between p and p1 for all entities.

And the query runs out of memory(14 Gb heap space allocated).So should i be resorting to graphx and other big data graph processing technologies to do this? or is there any thing that can be done to optimise?

Answer (score 1):

You apparently want to count the pairs of people who share any common interest.

Your current query (if it runs to completion) is actually returning double the right number, since every entity pair would be counted twice (as person1/person2 and person2/person1). Not only that, you are also using up double the memory.

## Naive solution

The following query eliminates duplicate pairs (and also any self-pairings) by imposing an order on the IDs of `p` and `p1`. It should use less memory, have better performance, and also give you an accurate result.

```
MATCH (p:Entity)-[:interestedIn]->(i:Interest)<-[:interestedIn]-(p1:Entity)
WHERE ID(p)> ID(p1)
RETURN count(*)
```

*However*, since this solution only cuts the memory requirement in half, it may still run out of memory.

## Enlightened solution

You can calculate the number of pairs without querying for them!

Given `N` entities with the same interest, there are `(N * (N-1))/2` possible unique pairs of those entities.

The following query uses that formula to come up with the answer without bothering to query for the pairs. It just queries for all the entities interested in each interest, calculates the number of pairs for each interest, and them sums up those totals.

```
MATCH (p:Entity)-[:interestedIn]->(i:Interest)
WITH i, (COUNT(p)*(COUNT(p)-1))/2 AS numPairs
RETURN SUM(numPairs);
```

This should greatly reduce the memory and CPU complexity, from O(N^2) to O(N).

Comment: I made a mistake in phrasing the question, my bad. What i was trying to do was create a relationship between entities with similarity value as attribute. Which is calculated lets say as commoninterests/sum of interests of both or cosine product of two vectors.

Comment: Please correct the wording of your question, and provide more details about the exact calculation you are trying to do.